# Firebase Realtime Database data written with this function is not deleted Why ? (java 8- Firebase Function)

Tags: java, function, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

The code that we check this database and have data the database added. The problem is that with this function, the data stored in the database is never deleted. If I delete the data, it will come back Why?

After the data was created, I tried to manually delete the firebase database from the interface.I tried to delete it with code via Android. I tried to write a new function and delete it.But in all of them the data is deleted first, and comes back in less than 10 seconds

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.*;


import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Serializable;


public class Example {


    public void helloWorld(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.write("Hello world!");


        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault())
                .setProjectId("***myproject***")
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://******myproject****.com")
                .build();


        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = mDatabase.getReference();


        myRef.child("Users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    //All User Get
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        User user = ds.getValue(User.class);
                        //Liked user Get
                        myRef.child("Users").child(user.getUserUid()).child("userLikeList").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                                    //Liked User and Liker user Matcher
                                    for (DataSnapshot ds1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                        User user1 = ds1.getValue(User.class);
                                        myRef.child("Users").child(user1.getUserUid()).child("userLikeList").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                                                    for (DataSnapshot ds2 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                                        if (user.getUserUid().equals(ds2.getKey())){
                                                            myRef.child("Users").child(user.getUserUid()).child("userMatchList").child(user1.getUserUid()).setValueAsync(user1);
                                                        }
                                                    }


                                                }
                                            }


                                            @Override
                                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {


                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }


                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {


                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {


            }
        });






    }
}


class User implements Serializable {
    public String userName;
    public String userEmail;
    public String userGender;
    public String userProfilPic;
    public String userDateBirth;
    public String userUid;
    public String userCity;
    public String userPremiumDate;
    public String userPremiumCode;
    public boolean userPremiumStatus;
    public double userLatitude;
    public double userLongitude;
    public int userAge;


    public User() {
    }


    public User(String userName, String userEmail, String userGender,
                String userProfilPic, String userDateBirth, String userUid, String userCity,
                String userPremiumDate, String userPremiumCode, boolean userPremiumStatus,
                double userLatitude, double userLongitude, int userAge) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
        this.userGender = userGender;
        this.userProfilPic = userProfilPic;
        this.userDateBirth = userDateBirth;
        this.userUid = userUid;
        this.userCity = userCity;
        this.userPremiumDate = userPremiumDate;
        this.userPremiumCode = userPremiumCode;
        this.userPremiumStatus = userPremiumStatus;
        this.userLatitude = userLatitude;
        this.userLongitude = userLongitude;
        this.userAge = userAge;
    }


    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }


    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }


    public String getUserEmail() {
        return userEmail;
    }


    public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
    }


    public String getUserGender() {
        return userGender;
    }


    public void setUserGender(String userGender) {
        this.userGender = userGender;
    }


    public String getUserProfilPic() {
        return userProfilPic;
    }


    public void setUserProfilPic(String userProfilPic) {
        this.userProfilPic = userProfilPic;
    }


    public String getUserDateBirth() {
        return userDateBirth;
    }


    public void setUserDateBirth(String userDateBirth) {
        this.userDateBirth = userDateBirth;
    }


    public String getUserUid() {
        return userUid;
    }


    public void setUserUid(String userUid) {
        this.userUid = userUid;
    }


    public String getUserCity() {
        return userCity;
    }


    public void setUserCity(String userCity) {
        this.userCity = userCity;
    }


    public String getUserPremiumDate() {
        return userPremiumDate;
    }


    public void setUserPremiumDate(String userPremiumDate) {
        this.userPremiumDate = userPremiumDate;
    }


    public String getUserPremiumCode() {
        return userPremiumCode;
    }


    public void setUserPremiumCode(String userPremiumCode) {
        this.userPremiumCode = userPremiumCode;
    }


    public boolean isUserPremiumStatus() {
        return userPremiumStatus;
    }


    public void setUserPremiumStatus(boolean userPremiumStatus) {
        this.userPremiumStatus = userPremiumStatus;
    }


    public double getUserLatitude() {
        return userLatitude;
    }


    public void setUserLatitude(double userLatitude) {
        this.userLatitude = userLatitude;
    }


    public double getUserLongitude() {
        return userLongitude;
    }


    public void setUserLongitude(double userLongitude) {
        this.userLongitude = userLongitude;
    }


    public int getUserAge() {
        return userAge;
    }


    public void setUserAge(int userAge) {
        this.userAge = userAge;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "userName='" + userName + '\'' +
                ", userEmail='" + userEmail + '\'' +
                ", userGender='" + userGender + '\'' +
                ", userProfilPic='" + userProfilPic + '\'' +
                ", userDateBirth='" + userDateBirth + '\'' +
                ", userUid='" + userUid + '\'' +
                ", userCity='" + userCity + '\'' +
                ", userPremiumDate='" + userPremiumDate + '\'' +
                ", userPremiumCode='" + userPremiumCode + '\'' +
                ", userPremiumStatus=" + userPremiumStatus +
                ", userLatitude=" + userLatitude +
                ", userLongitude=" + userLongitude +
                ", userAge=" + userAge +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you shared is for a Java process. How is this related to Cloud Functions (which you tagged your question with)?

Comment: I have a record in beta cloud function.Writeable functions in Java

Comment: What exactly does your Cloud Function do?  It sounds like the way you've coded it, it's writing data back to the database after it's changed in some way.

Comment: The http address reads the database when a call is made and check the database and add a data.ıt's just doing it.task to read the database and write new data, but only when the http address is called

Comment: When I manually delete the data written by the function from the database, it works automatically even though I have triggered the http function. why is this happening.i have written http function just to make it work when i call